# Ecto multi build_assoc on a list

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to insert a list in a multi transaction with a `has_many`. Something like :

```
Ecto.Multi.new()
|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:main, Main.changeset(%Main{}, attrs))
|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:child, fn %{main: main} ->
  Ecto.build_assoc(main, :child, %{name: "aaa"}) # inserts just one
end)
|> Ecto.Multi.run(:child, fn _, %{main: main} ->
  Enum.map(attrs.children, &create_child/1) # doesn't return a multi and doesn't build the assoc
end)
|> Repo.transaction()
```

As i commented out, I don't find a working solution.

```
|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:child, fn %{main: main} ->
  Ecto.build_assoc(main, :child, %{name: "aaa"})
end)
```

This inserts just one row, I have a list to insert.

```
|> Ecto.Multi.run(:child, fn _, %{main: main} ->
  Enum.map(attrs.children, &create_child/1)
end)
```

This doesn't return a multi and doesn't build the assoc with `main`.

I found this form also, but it's intended for a single insert as well :

```
|> Multi.run(:user, fn %{organisation: organisation} ->
  User.changeset(User, user_params)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(organisation)
  |> Repo.insert # returns a {:ok, user} or {:error, changeset}
end)
```

Comment: What is your question? I don’t see any issue here: whether you want to insert it, go ahead.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I edited my question, sorry it wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#content) is named not after inserting *multiple records*, but after *grouping multiple operations* within a single transaction.

There is [`Ecto.Multi.insert_all/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#insert_all/5), but it has the same limitations as [`Repo.insert_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3), namely, there is no way to insert into several tables. (Also it does not support automatic timestamps and has several other limitations.)

Just use normal iteration `Enum.each/2` or like, produce as many insert statements as needed, and wrap all of them into a transaction.

---

To collect several *children* into `Ecto.Multi` one might use `Enum.reduce` with `Ecto.Multi` as an accumulator:

```
multi =
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:main, Main.changeset(%Main{}, attrs))

attrs.children
|> Enum.reduce(
    multi,
    &Ecto.Multi.insert(&2, :child, create_child(&1))
  )
|> Repo.transaction()
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Although, there is no solution to keep the structure I have been trying and make this happen ?

Comment: I do not follow. RDBMS does not support multiple inserts into several tables. Ecto does not support it. Keep your structure, just insert records one by one.

Comment: I'm really having a hard time explaining myself today ^^ I meant the code structure, not the DB structure. Using a `multi` with pipes, namely.

Comment: `Enum.reduce(children, Multi.new, fn child, multi -> Multi.insert(multi, :child, fn -> ...end) end)` would do.

Comment: Your code snippet is awesome ! One more little thing though... `child` needs to have `main_id`, as an assoc or at least as a property added to `&1`... How to get it from previous multi and add it ?

Comment: Declare it upfront, assign to the local variable and use it whenever needed.

Comment: Sure, but I don't find how to get it out of the multi operation. `Enum.into(Ecto.Multi.to_list(multi), %{}).main` gives a tuple `{:insert, #Ecto.Changeset...` - but how to get the id from there ? That's the main reason I was trying to make it work in a `Ecto.multi.run` in the first place, to get the changes so far...

Comment: I seem to finally understand what do you want to achieve. Use `Ecto.build_assoc/4` instead of `Ecto.Multi.insert/3`. `ID` at this moment is not available yet, since the actual DB insert did not happen.

Comment: Sure, I already tried that, it's in my initial question, but `build_assoc` doesn't take a list - and used with `Enum.reduce` it have the same problem as `Multi.insert` - needs the changes so far, thus the `main`, to work !

Comment: Found a solution - running `Enum.reduce` inside of a `Multi.run` block :)

Comment: Great to hear! Congrats :)

Comment: @JeremyBelolo I ran into the same problem as you and am curious about your final solution. Would you mind adding another answer to the question with your solution? That would be much appreciated!